# standard action button disappears after override

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, partner-communities, button-overrides, salesforce-classic

We have set-up a partner community for our customer where we have overridden the "new" button on account with a visualforce page (for "classic") and a lightning component (for "lex").

In the "classic" community this works perfectly, in the "lightning" community the button is not visible as soon as the override is activated.

For full license users (ex: administrator) the button remains available and is working as expected, both in "lex" as in "classic" UI.

Do any of you have an explanation for this behavior? And preferably a solution as well :)

Thx

Comment: Did you check the layout being the same for the two and if the button was available in the lightning section for the community users ?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced a similar issue of the standard button becoming invisible on overriding them with a custom lightning component.One possible workaround is to create a custom component having just the button.Now place this button component on your community page through community builder.You can define your custom component as a child of this button component.

Comment: i also facing same issue, can you please elaborate your suggestions.