# Standard action button disappears in communities after over ride with custom lightning component

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

I tried to override sobject "New" Button with below code, it's working in salesforce lightning experience. the same sobject i am using in Community navigation menu item.

```
<aura:component Implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >
<div>custom overridden Lightning component</div>
</aura:component>
```

but in community after click the sobject menu item lists shows and all other standards buttons are visible in list view top right corner except overridden "New" button.
i found [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207961/standard-action-button-disappears-after-override) after i search in forum.

is there any ways to get those overridden components in to community.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever stumbles upon this thread, you need to also allow the override in the community administration settings.

Go to Your Community -> Workspaces -> Administration -> Preferences and check "Override standard actions with a Lightning component" checkbox.

Not sure why Salesforce has this as an additional setting on the community but that could very well be your problem.